# Difference between pre-installed Ubuntu and self-installed Ubuntu

Tags: installation, preinstallation

Is there a difference if you buy an Computer with Ubuntu pre-installed and if you install Ubuntu yourself? Are there any merits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct benefit is that you don't have to install Ubuntu yourself. This makes it an attractive option for novice users who may not be comfortable installing an operating system, thus allowing Ubuntu to better compete with preinstalled Windows systems.

Also, if the system has Ubuntu instead of Windows, you don't have to pay the "Microsoft tax", by buying a computer with Windows which you won't use and then installing Ubuntu.

Finally, a preinstalled Ubuntu version may contain additional tweaks and drivers to allow Ubuntu to utilize all the features in the hardware. Sometimes "stock" Ubuntu will  run poorly on a particular system, but the preinstalled version is specifically tuned by the manufacturer to work correctly.

That doesn't mean that you'll be forever stuck with the version of Ubuntu that came preinstalled; usually the changes to make the system work are merged with the next version of stock Ubuntu.